# How to build tizen source?

Tags: build, tizen

I have downloaded all the sources of tizen OS from their web site. It consists of about 1040 projects. Now I want to build the whole projects. In their website they mentioned that we have to use gbs (git build system) to build the sources. As they told I have set the configuration  file and tried to build. But I m not able to build and I was getting messages like,.

`"fatal: ref HEAD is not a symbolic ref"`

and I was getting errors when it tries to build all the x86 packages. I didn't modified tizen code, and still I m getting these errors.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your working branch name is (nobranch), please checkout to correct/existing branch in your repo.

Check your branch using

```
git branch
```

It will show you **no branch**

Checkout correct branch that you want to build using

```
git checkout branchname
```

And you can't build **x86** pkgs using gbs, but you can build **i586** or **armv7l** pkgs using gbs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the whole package set using repo and then build the right branch (ie: tizen) using gbs along profile repo's ...

Or consider to build using yocto if profile supported